# How to keep observable chain going after http error in one observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

I've got a chain of observables. Here is the piece of code:

```
        //get dynamic tree 
      flatMap(res => this.dynamicReportId !== null ? this.reportService.getDynamicTree(this.dynamicReportId) : of({})),
      tap(res => this.dynamicTree = res),
        //get dynamic report 
      flatMap((res) => this.dynamicReportId !== null ? this.reportService.getDynamicReport(this.dynamicReportId) : of({})),
```

However when I got 500 API error from the first request(get dynamic tree), the chain stops and never enters the second flatMap(dynamic report).

Here is the function `this.reportService.getDynamicTree()`:

```
 get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}${path}`, {headers: this.setHeaders(true), params: params}).pipe(
      catchError(error => this.processError(path, error)),
      map((res: Response) => res));
  }
```

where `this.processError` returns `observableThrowError(res);`

What should I return in case of error to continue the chain? Or is the reason in other things?

Comment: If you get 500 error from server, what would you pass to the next chain? The chain is expected to be executed only if you get success result from server.

Comment: The next chain doesn't depend on the previous exactly here. Is there any possibility to return empty observable or anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of an error, an `Observable` completes, so if you want to return a new `Observable` after an error occurs, you have to use the `catchError` operator like this:

```
//get dynamic tree 
flatMap(res => this.dynamicReportId !== null ? this.reportService.getDynamicTree(this.dynamicReportId) : of({})),
tap(res => this.dynamicTree = res),
catchError(() => of({})),
//get dynamic report 
flatMap((res) => this.dynamicReportId !== null ? this.reportService.getDynamicReport(this.dynamicReportId) : of({})),
```

The `tap` operator safely doesn't execute the callback and just forwards errors when they occur so that will assign `this.dynamicTree` only in case of a success.

If you want to handle the error in the service instead of the component, you have to return something else than `observableThrowError(res);` from `processError` (for example `of({})`) but that will execute the `tap` callback and assign `this.dynamicTree` which is probably an unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First of - continuing the chain kind of defeats the whole concept of a chain. However, I think this issue should be resolveable by having some fairly simple chain iterator and handling errors thrown by HttpClient and service.

I created a StackBlitz example with my solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/chain. For simplycity, the chain returns data in `{ result: any, error: any }[]`. Of course you will be able to do pretty much anything in terms of piping operators to adjust the result.

Ideally, the `observableChain` functionality would be separate and handling the empty results as you need it to - in your case instead of returning `{ result: any, error: any }[]` it would return `{}` on error response and log the error.